# Terraform: Cross project referencing not allowed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm seeing something strange with `google_compute_firewall`, the compute instance is in a shared subnet.

I assume a firewall rule needs to be associated to the network which that subnet belongs to. But we can't add the firewall rule to that network because:

```
google_compute_firewall.intacct-firewall: Error creating Firewall: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.network': 'projects/it-production-186816/global/networks/production'. Cross project referencing is not allowed for this resource., invalid
```

Unable to find anything documented for firewall rules on shared networks. Are we to add the firewall to the local VPC and not the shared VPC?

The compute image has this network configuration:

```
  network_interface {
    subnetwork         = "${var.subnetwork}"
    subnetwork_project = "${var.vpc_parent}"
    access_config      = {
      nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.dokku.address}"
    }
  }
```

So although the compute instance is in `project-1`, the network it's using is in `project-2`

EDIT:

My main.tf:

```
# Backend config
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket      = "intacct-staging-remote-backend"
    project     = "fr-intacct-staging"
    credentials = "./creds/serviceaccount.json"
  }
}
#
# Provider config
provider "google" {
  region      = "${var.gcp_region}"
  project     = "${var.gcp_project}"
  credentials = "${file("./creds/serviceaccount.json")}"
}
#
# Static IP Address for the app
resource "google_compute_address" "dokku" {
  name = "fr-intacct-staging-ip"
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
}
#
# Compute Instance Config
resource "google_compute_instance" "dokku" {
  project                   = "${var.gcp_project}"
  name                      = "dokku-host1"
  machine_type              = "${var.comp_type}"
  zone                      = "${var.gcp_zone}"
  allow_stopping_for_update = "true"

  tags = ["intacct"]

  # Install Dokku
  metadata_startup_script   = <<SCRIPT
sudo yum install -y wget
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dokku/dokku/v0.14.5/bootstrap.sh
sudo DOKKU_TAG=${var.dokku_version} bash bootstrap.sh
sudo dokku apps:create fr-intacct-staging
sudo echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo systemctl restart network
setenforce 0
SCRIPT

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "${var.compute_image}"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork         = "${var.subnetwork}"
    subnetwork_project = "${var.vpc_parent}"
    access_config      = {
      nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.dokku.address}"
    }
  }
}
#
# Firewall rule for app access
resource "google_compute_firewall" "intacct-firewall" {
  name    = "intacct-firewall"
  network = "projects/it-production-186816/global/networks/production"
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = [ "80" ]
  }
  source_ranges = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
  target_tags   = [ "intacct" ]
}
```

It seems wrong to be using another provider config for the other project to add a firewall rule.

If it is that way, then so be it... but since the service account in use has permission on the other project, it seems wrong that we'd have to use another provider for the other project?

Comment: We would need to take a look at the terraform code to be able to answer your post correctly, you should have multiple declaration in fact as you have more than one project?

Comment: I don't have multiple projects. It's a shared VPC. so the compute instance is using the other projects network. I've added more details to the original post.

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue with the error, you should execute your terraform in the project where the network is declared.

If it's project-2 (as you are in a multiple project env), you should execute your terraform on project-2 and not declare your terraform to use project-1 to do configuration in another project. That's exactly what the error is telling you :)

**UPDATE**

Let's be even more precise.

So you could declare another provider, it's what I would prefer to do as I would know precisely where the code is executed and the project, but you could also try to specify the project inside the resource like you did on the compute instance, for the firewall rule:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "intacct-firewall" {
  project = "projcet-2"
  name    = "intacct-firewall"
  network = "projects/it-production-186816/global/networks/production"
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = [ "80" ]
  }
  source_ranges = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
  target_tags   = [ "intacct" ]
}
```

There is a catch to doing this, the service account you are using should have rights to do thing in both projects.

Comment: I've added some more detail to my original post. I'm just not sure this sounds right....

Comment: So, the example you provided is exactly what i tried originally... which cause the original error I posted. Apologies as I can see I was fairly vague in the first instance.

Comment: Ok if this does not work, the first solution I gave is the best option you have. Create a separate terraform for the firewall rules to run on the other project

Comment: You say 'create another terraform' but... we can't have multiple providers. So I can't use another tf file. I suppose I'd have to have a separate module? Even still, I am unsure as to whether we'd be able to have another provider.. `Error: provider.google: multiple configurations present; only one configuration is allowed per provider`

Comment: Create another folder with a new provider and use this folder to execute in the second projet...

Comment: The problem I found with that approach is that is disconnects the firewall creation from whatever else you're spinning up.  Our Terraform service account has Network Admin privileges in the host project, thus allowing it to deploy the firewall changes associated with rest of the functionality (assuming you set the firewall project equal to the host name).  However, this means we have to ensure that not everyone has the key for the Terraform service account

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was to create another local module for creating the firewall rule in the host project.

Answer (score 0):

Just listing another scenario where this issue `Cross project referencing is not allowed for this resource.` can occur !!

say you configure your cloud shell variables to use `tf_project_123` and in your `providers.tf` you mention your project as `tf_project_321`. Then this issue occurs.

In my case, I was using google cloud shell from `tf_project_321` project & I used `tf_project_123` in my providers file. All I had to do was update my gcloud project details (shell command - `gcloud config set project tf_project_123`)

When providing details to terraform tool, just ensure the providers project details, permissions and shell vars are in sync.